# Math.sin() Different Precision between Node.js and C#

Tags: javascript, c#, node.js, math, trigonometry

I have a problem in precision in the last digit after the comma.The javascript code generates one less Digit in compare with the C# code.

Here is the simple Node.js code

```
var seed = 45;
var x = Math.sin(seed) * 0.5;
console.log(x);//0.4254517622670592
```

Here is the simple C# code

```
public String pseudorandom()
{
    int seed = 45;
    double num = Math.Sin(seed) * (0.5);
    return num.ToString("G15");//0.42545176226705922
}
```

How to achieve the same precision?

Comment: You're comparing the results of the two languages converting the numeric form to a string. What are you really trying to achieve? What exactly is the source of your interest in "precision"? Both languages use native IEEE 754 floating point.

Comment: I am trying to achieve the same precision.I can't understand your negative vote.

Comment: I didn't downvote; I'm just trying to figure out what you're trying to do. You're printing out the numeric value, which in both cases involves converting the value to a string so that it can be printed. There's no guarantee that the rules of both languages for doing that are the same.

Comment: What about **G14**

Comment: The full decimal representation of the binary result is `0.425451762267059219180254103775951080024242401123046875` resulting from something like `G55`.

Comment: Of course, that is only the x86 value. A more correct value computed in multi-precision arithmetic for this expression is `0.4254517622670592124311898388090205595403298367592972483759281`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JavaScript [Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) type is quite complex. It looks like floating point number will probably be like  IEEE 754-2008 but some aspects are left to the implementation. See http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-number-objects sec 12.7.

There is a note

> The output of toFixed may be more precise than toString for some
>   values because toString only prints enough significant digits to
>   distinguish the number from adjacent number values. For example,
>
> `(1000000000000000128).toString()` returns "1000000000000000100", while
>   `(1000000000000000128).toFixed(0)` returns "1000000000000000128".

Hence to get full digit accuracy you need something like

```
seed = 45;
x = Math.sin(seed) * 0.5;
x.toFixed(17);
// on my platform its "0.42545176226705922"
```

Also, note the specification for how the implementation of sin and cos allow for some variety in the actual algorithm. It's only guaranteed to within +/- 1 ULP.

Using java the printing algorithm is different. Even forcing 17 digits gives the result as 0.42545176226705920.

You can check you are getting the same bit patterns using `x.toString(2)` and `Double.doubleToLongBits(x)` in Java.

Answer (score 2):

```
return num.ToString("G15");//0.42545176226705922
```

actually returns "0.425451762267059" (no significant digit + 15 decimal places in this example), and not the precision shown in the comment after.

So you would use:

```
return num.ToString("G16");
```

to get "0.4254517622670592"

(for your example - where the significant digit is always 0) `G16` will be 16 decimal places.